# Is it a good practice to add code brackets to technical terms?

Tags: discussion, markdown, information-display, best-practices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Highlighting technical words?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155904/highlighting-technical-words)

Is it a good practice to add code brackets to Classes or Technical terms when asking or answering questions? Ex:

- "Put the `String` in the end of the line...."
- "In `Visual Studio` do this or that..."
- "The `Exception` is there..."

I was wondering about this because when I write Javadocs I add {@code } to some technical terms and makes them stand out of the bunch of words so I was wondering if same applies to SO. ex:

```
/**
 * Called when a new user has successfully register. It will add records in
 * then kind having X and Y push notifications set to
 * {@code true;} All other Kinds set to {@code false;}
 */
```

Comment: No. No. No. Backticks are for inline **code**, nothing more nothing less. I'm horrified again and again at edits ruining posts by backticking virtually ANYTHING, to a point of rolling back such edits.

Comment: I can distinctly remember this question being asked before.

Comment: I tried searching meta with no results before I asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the type of formatting that you are using is for inline code blocks. Don't use this to highlight technical terms as it just clutters up the interface and makes it hard to read.

**As an example, this would be okay:**

I used this statement in my code: `alert('hello world');`

**Whereas this would be unnecessary:**

How should I instantiate a `String`?  << This is bad.

**From the editing help section (click the Question mark when editing to see the editing help section):**

> To create not a block, but an inline code span, use backticks:
>
> ```
>  The `$` character is just a shortcut for `window.jQuery`.
> ```

**Lastly, based on the example in the guide, it would be okay to use inline code blocks when an exact syntactic representation is needed to describe something:**

You should use the identifier `String` to declare variables that hold text in Java, such as `String myName = "Billy Bob";`

Comment: Thanks for the constructive answer.